# Does bash think this argument is a command?

Tags: bash, printf, wc

In a bash script I have this line

```
$var=$(printf "$otherVar" | wc -l)
```

which is failing with the error

> ../test.sh: line 30: =60: command not found

which I find entirely inscrutable. Presumably `=60` is something it found in the contents of `$otherVar`, but why would that cause problems for either `printf` or `wc`? It should just be data.

Comment: could you provide a complete example value of  `$otherVar` ?

Comment: Remove the $ from $var. Assignments in bash don’t take $ on the left hand side.

Comment: @Inian Aah! Stupid mistake, doesn't appear on any of the other assignments but wouldn't you know... Thanks!